# How to generate a GMF diagram from another GMF diagram?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-gmf

Let's say, I have an Ecore model A (containing ClassP, ClassQ) for which I generated a graphical editor using GMF. Now, I have another Ecore model B wich is a superset of model A. Say, it has ClassX, ClassY, ClassP, ClassQ.

What I want to do is, to design a graphical representation using the GMF editor based on model A, and then, to be able to import that diagram in the GMF diagram editor which is based on model B, so that I don't have to draw the elements of model A again in the generated diagram which uses model B.

Is this posslible somehow? At least something close to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe its late and you already have the solution, but yetserday I was reading this tutorial, maybe it will help! http://gmfsamples.tuxfamily.org/wiki/doku.php?id=emf_tutorial2.
Also in the emf book in chapter 13 there are some pages related with this. I am not sure if this is what you need, but I hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. Almost did the same thing. :)